# printing binomial coefficient using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-programming

Binomial coefficient for given value of n and k(nCk)
using numpy to multiply the results of a for loop
but numpy method is returning the memory location not the result
pls provide better solution in terms of time complexity if possible.
or any other suggestions.

```
import time
import numpy
def binomialc(n,k):
    return 1 if k==0 or k==n else numpy.prod((n+1-i)/i for i in range(1,k+1))
starttime=time.perf_counter()
print(binomialc(600,298))
print(time.perf_counter()-starttime)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `numpy`?

Comment: suggest any other method @norok2

Comment: Instead of `numpy.prod((n+1-i)/i for i in range(1,k+1))`, write as `i = np.arange(1, k+1); np.prod(n + 1 - i / i)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use: [`scipy.special.binom()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.binom.html)

or, since Python 3.8: [`math.comb()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.comb)

---

## EDIT

I am not quite sure why you would not want to use [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/) but you are OK with [NumPy](https://numpy.org/), as SciPy is a well-established library from essentially the same folks developing NumPy.

Anyway, here a couple of other methods:

- using `math.factorial`:

```
import math


def binom(n, k):
    return math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(k) // math.factorial(n - k)
```

- using `prod()` and `math.factorial()` (theoretically more efficient, but not in practice):

```
def prod(items, start=1):
    for item in items:
        start *= item
    return start


def binom_simplified(n, k):
    if k > n - k:
        return prod(range(k + 1, n + 1)) // math.factorial(n - k)
    else:
        return prod(range(n - k + 1, n + 1)) // math.factorial(k)
```

- using `numpy.prod()`:

```
import numpy as np


def binom_np(n, k):
    return 1 if k == 0 or k == n else np.prod([(n + 1 - i) / i for i in range(1, k + 1)])
```

---

Speed-wise, `scipy.special.binom()` is the fastest by far and large, but if you need the exact value also for very large numbers, you may prefer `binom()` (somewhat surprisingly even over `math.comb()`).

```
%timeit scipy.special.binom(600, 298)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 µs per loop
print(scipy.special.binom(600, 298))
# 1.3332140543730587e+179

%timeit math.comb(600, 298)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 75.6 µs per loop
print(math.binom(600, 298))
# 133321405437268991724586879878020905773601074858558174180536459530557427686938822154484588609548964189291743543415057988154692680263088796451884071926401665548516571367537285901600

%timeit binom(600, 298)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 36.5 µs per loop
print(binom(600, 298))
# 133321405437268991724586879878020905773601074858558174180536459530557427686938822154484588609548964189291743543415057988154692680263088796451884071926401665548516571367537285901600

%timeit binom_np(600, 298)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 45.8 µs per loop
print(binom_np(600, 298))
# 1.3332140543726893e+179

%timeit binom_simplified(600, 298)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 41.9 µs per loop
print(binom_simplified(600, 298))
# 133321405437268991724586879878020905773601074858558174180536459530557427686938822154484588609548964189291743543415057988154692680263088796451884071926401665548516571367537285901600
```

Comment: i dont know scipy pls suggest any other method

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/index.html or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scipy/index.htm